# Get files from guest to host in vagrant

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

Can I retrieve the files from my vagrant machine (guest) and sync it to my host machine?

I know sync folders work the other way around but I was hoping there is a way to make it in reverse? Instead of synching files from the host machine to the guest machine; retrieve the files from inside the guest machine and have it exposed on the host machine.

Thanks.

Comment: Which files are you trying to sync from the Guest to the Host?

Answer (score 9):

Why not just put them in the /vagrant folder of your vagrant vm. This is a special mounted folder from the host (where Vagrantfile) resides to the guest.

This way you do not have to worry about doing any other copy operations between hosts.

```
$ ls
Vagrantfile
$ vagrant ssh
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-42-generic x86_64)
Last login: Wed Oct 12 12:05:53 2016 from 10.0.2.2
vagrant@vagrant-virtualbox:~$ ls /vagrant
Vagrantfile
vagrant@vagrant-virtualbox:~$ cd /vagrant
vagrant@vagrant-virtualbox:/vagrant$ touch hello
vagrant@vagrant-virtualbox:/vagrant$ exit
logout
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
$ ls
Vagrantfile             hello
$
```

Answer (score 5):

have you tried to scp files between your host and your virtual machine ? As I remember, the ssh login and password are "vagrant".

Something like this could do the job :

`scp vagrant@<vm_ip>:<path_to_file> <path_to_dest_on_your_host>`

Comment: If you have another user instead of the default `vagrant`, you should substitute `vagrant` by your username in the above command. If you have not set a password manually, try using your username as password.

Answer (score 3):

Using scp with private key will make this much easy!

```
scp -i ./.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key -r -P2222 vagrant@127.0.0.1:/home/vagrant/somefolder ./
```

Comment: I'm getting error:
`ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused`

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [vagrant-rsync-back](https://github.com/smerrill/vagrant-rsync-back).  I've not tried it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Install python then run, e.g.

```
$ nohup python3.6 -m SimpleHTTPServer &
```

in the output directory.  I put this command in a file set to run always during provisioning.  This solution required zero system configuration.